# Google place picker does not start

Tags: google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I am trying to initiate google place picker on a dialog box but it doesn't start.
Below is the code i am using:

```
package com.settings.android.elisea;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;


public class AddContact extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button location;
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addaction);
        location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.location);
        location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

                Intent intent;
                try {
                    intent = builder.build(AddContact.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final String address = place.getAddress() + "";
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }
            location.setText(address);
            location.setText(address);
            location.setText(address);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.settings.android.elisea">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AddContact"></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_place_api"></meta-data>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

I have already created an API in google credentials but i don't think that is the problem since it is not starting nor displaying any irregularities.